# Present auto calculation when opening workbook for the first time

Tags: excel, vba

The issue I'm facing is as follows:
I've got a workbook with 13 sheets (one per each month of the year + general sheet). A simple VBA code enters a timestamp to a cell ("Order date") if the value in an adjacent cell change ("Order quantity"). All is working fine.
However, when I'm emailing this workbook to someone else, and that person saves the workbook on her local machine, once the workbook is opened ALL TIMESTAMPs are updated according to the date and time when the workbook is opened. After the first time the workbook is opened, it works fine again (timestamps don't change). The issue is ONLY at the first time the file is opened after being emailed.

I tried solving the issue by creating a "First time open" flag. Whenever this flag is turned on, auto calculation is disabled (xlCalculationManual). When I enable auto calculation (once the flag is turned off) excel calculate the entire workbook and all timestamps are changing. So, this solution is not working.
Any ideas on how to solve that issue?
Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: Is the file administrated by you ( or one person)? Can VBA be disabled for everyone else but you or other admins?

Comment: I built the workbook but it's being used by other people. They obviously need the VBA since it's required to use the timestemp function (which is a UDF) and some other features.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend for the dates to never change, simply change the formulas (eg `=TODAY()`) into values.

1. Select the data
2. Copy it <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
3. PasteSpecial <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd> +  <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
4. Paste as Values

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Orders (and thus order's date) are entered by the end user in different cells at different times. I wouldn't like the end user changing the date to value after every time she place a new order.

Comment: Is there a way to disable auto calculation for a RANGE?  I only found a way to disable auto calculation for the entire worksheet.